# How to modify the response code of a website in burp?

Tags: burp-suite

Imagine website `http://x.x.x.x//thing.php` returns a response code of 302 instead of 200, meaning I get redirected to `http://x.x.x.x//other.php` instead of going to `http://x.x.x.x//thing.php`.

Can I use Burp to intercept and modify the response code, changing it to 200 and going to `http://x.x.x.x/thing.php` itself? If so, how?

Comment: You cannot change from the client side what the server does. Changing an error code does nothing to change what the server is programmed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get anything from `thing.php` - at least unless you change somehow your initial query.

You should be able to see in Burp the initial response you get, the one that gives you HTTP 302 - that is *exactly* what `thing.php` does when presented a request you've made. You ain't going to get anything else from it, unless you modify your initial query (but in this case, there's no point modifying the response in Burp anyway - you will get it from the request itself).